# SD card required to download error in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard, android-studio-2.3

I am using android studio 2.3. Created an AVD with API level 17 (Jelly bean). After this i am trying to download something in emulator and it gives "An SD card is required to download abc.apk" error.

I tried multiple things already : 
used mksdcard, tried running emulator from command line using sdcard.img path, provided space in studio-sdcard section. in my config.ini hw.sdCard is set to yes, still facing this issue.

Looking for help to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: This seems to be a bug. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=240155 . In comment #2 there is a workaround that I was not able to make work yet.

Comment: If you are blocked by this issue in a personal project, you might consider using Genymotion in the mean-time (https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)